# How to make my query customized in SQL Reporting services

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

> I want to make my query customized in SQL Reporting services . It does
>   not have an option to add and remove code from the dataset .

My query is :

```
WITH Requests AS
(
SELECT
CASE

WHEN Request LIKE '%greenhopper%'  THEN 'GreenHopper' 
WHEN Request LIKE '%gadget%'  THEN 'Dashboard' 
WHEN Request LIKE '%admin%'  THEN 'Admin'
WHEN Request LIKE '%AssignIssue%' or  Request LIKE '%AttachFile%'  THEN 'Update Issue'
WHEN Request LIKE '%Create%' THEN 'Create Issue'
WHEN Request LIKE '%EditIssue%'  THEN 'Edit Issue'
WHEN Request LIKE '%GET /browse%'  THEN 'Browse Project'
WHEN Request LIKE '%GET /sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-xml%'  THEN 'Export'
WHEN Request LIKE '%logout%' or Request LIKE '%Logout!default.jspa%'  THEN 'Logout' 
WHEN Request LIKE '%AddComment.jspa%'  THEN 'Comment'
WHEN Request LIKE 'GET /secure/projectavatar?pid%' THEN 'Project Avatar'


ELSE 'Others'
END RequestType
FROM LogData where (convert(nvarchar(10), TimeLog, 120) between (@StartDate) and  (@EndDate))
and ( CAST(TimeLog AS TIME) between  (@StartTiming) and  (@EndTiming))
)
SELECT
RequestType,
COUNT(*) RequesCount
FROM Requests
GROUP BY RequestType order by RequesCount DESC
```

> I want that some one can add and remove "When Remove LIKE ......... "
>   statement according to his own criteria . But the Problem is in Report
>   Builder of Reporting services there is no option to do something like
>   this .
>
> I was planning to make a separate GUI-Application in Java to do the
>   configuration , but there is no file containing the query . I don't
>   know where and how is it stored .
>
> Please can someone tell me how can I find this code or some Solution
>   to do this .  I am attaching the screen shot of report builder

[image: report builder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to make an expression out of your query. Click the Fx button to the right of the Query box. You would have to create an expression something like this:

```
="With Requests as....When request like" + Parameters!QueryCriteria.Value + "Else 'Others'..."
```

Create a parameter to store the value from the user (QueryCriteria in this case). You need to build the report before you convert the query to an expression so that Report Builder can build the fields for the dataset correctly.